# 2d графика в ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Какие есть инструменты для рисования в 2d по координатам в ASP.NET Core? И можно пример использования пожалуйста.

Comment: Уточните: вы хотите рисовать на клиентской стороне - в браузере пользователя? Или рисовать на сервере - создавать некое изображение, которое потом возвращается целиком?

Comment: У меня в начале вводятся параметры от пользователя по которым рассчитываются размеры и потом нужно чтобы по этим размерам создавалось изображение. Если правильно понял, то на сервере, а клиенту готовое изображение (ему его редактировать не нужно).

Comment: [Тут](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowDoYouUseSystemDrawingInNETCore.aspx) и как использовать GDI+, и ссылки на кросс-платформенные альтернативы

Comment: Там показано приложение, которое изменяет размер PNG до 128x128. Т.е. можно по его примеру сделать создание изображение по координатам, затем сохранение в PNG и вывод изображение в представление? Я правильно понял?